# How to send array in Ajax and get it in PHP as array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I want to send in ajax array in js, get it in php as an array and insert into with sql.

My ajax call looks like:

```
jQuery("#Save").click(function () {
  $(".linesView").each(function () {
    var action_name = "";
    if (window.current_category === "Expenses") {
      action_name = "Save_Expenses"
    } else if(window.current_category === "Incomes") {
      action_name = "Save_Incomes"
    }
    var line_id = $(this).attr("id").substring(5);
    var category = $("#CategoryValue_" + line_id).html();
    var date = $("#DateValue_" + line_id).html();
    var amount = $("#AmountValue_" + line_id).val();
    var repeated = $("#RepeatedValue_" + line_id).html();
    var note = $("#NoteValue_" + line_id).val();
    var data = json_encode([category,date,amount,repeated,note]);

    $.post("AjaxHandler.php", { "action_name": action_name, "data": data }, function () {
       //$("#ExpensesId_" + id).css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
});
```

The PHP code that needs to get the ajax call and add the data (by sql insert) looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST['action_name','data'])) {
  $action_name = $_POST['action_name'];
  $data=json_decode($_POST['data']);
  $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Expenses (accountid, category, date, amount, repeated) VALUES ('$accountid', '$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '0')");
}
```

The `accountid` coming from the top of the page, I already do delete action and it works fine, so the `accountid` is ok. All others, I don't know.

I tried to do encode and then decode. I am not sure if the syntax is right. Anyway if I didn't write elegant code, please show me how it needs to look. Maybe i need to take each param from the data and not to call `data[x]`?

Comment: `json_encode` is not a valid javascript function, it's a php function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to fix several mistakes. I also indented your code sample so that it renders properly - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Also, please note that you do not need to add call for help at the bottom or beginning of your question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()`

```
var data = ([category,date,amount,repeated,note]);
$.post("AjaxHandler.php", { "action_name": action_name, "data": JSON.stringify(data) }, function () {
  //$("#ExpensesId_" + id).css('display', 'none');
});
```

Comment: the ajax is work fine now i think but the php insert didnt work, maybe the insert is not right? its not take the '$data[0]' mayben i sould add special char to mark its a php var?

Comment: Try a `print_r($data)` in your php see how the data is received out there form console, then you can iterate, and I think your query is just fine, we need to check how the data is showing up

Answer (score 0):

Encode the data array to JSON string using **[`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)** in javascript. At server side use **[`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** to decode the data.

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery("#Save").click(function() {
  $(".linesView").each(function() {
    var action_name = "";
    if (window.current_category === "Expenses") {
      action_name = "Save_Expenses"
    } else if (window.current_category === "Incomes") {
      action_name = "Save_Incomes"
    }
    var line_id = $(this).attr("id").substring(5);
    var category = $("#CategoryValue_" + line_id).html();
    var date = $("#DateValue_" + line_id).html();
    var amount = $("#AmountValue_" + line_id).val();
    var repeated = $("#RepeatedValue_" + line_id).html();
    var note = $("#NoteValue_" + line_id).val();
    var data = JSON.stringify([category, date, amount, repeated, note]);
    //-----------------^--- Array to JSON string 
    $.post("AjaxHandler.php", {
      "action_name": action_name,
      "data": data
    }, function() {
      //$("#ExpensesId_" + id).css('display', 'none');
    });
  });
});
```

**PHP :**

```
if(isset($_POST['action_name','data'])){
    $action_name = $_POST['action_name'];
    $data=json_decode(json_decode($_POST['data']));
    //-----^--- decoding JSON string
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO Expenses (accountid, category, date, amount, repeated) VALUES ('$accountid', '$data[0]', '$data[1]', '$data[2]', '0')");
}
```